# Having trouble formatting URLComponents queryItems string

Tags: ios, swift

I am fetching a code from a url param and trying to store it in a variable so i can use that code elsewhere

```
var codeParam: URLQueryItem?

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
            print("URL \(key)")

            let components = URLComponents(url: key as! URL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
            print("COMPONETS \(String(describing: components?.queryItems))")

            if let queryItems = components?.queryItems {
              codeParam = queryItems.first { $0.name == "code" }
            }

            print(codeParam?.value!)
}
```

This current code prints out

`Optional("jcNRibc2esPOY40RM6MEp2PUClYO4H")`

but i need it to only print

`jcNRibc2esPOY40RM6MEp2PUClYO4H`

Comment: You have to unwrapped value from optional(codeParam, value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```swift
extension URL {
    var codeItem: String {
        let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        return components?.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == "code" })?.value ?? ""
    }
}
```

It first checks to see if the URL is valid.
Then checks to see if there are any queryItems.
Then checks to see if there is a query item with the name "code".
Then returns the value if all the checks are successful, otherwise it returns an empty String.

Use it like this `myURL.codeItem`

If you want to keep with the code you already have, then simply do this:

`print(codeParam?.value ?? "")`

Comment: im basically already doing that but not in an extension and i still get optional(" ") in it

Comment: No, you aren't. If you were doing what I did then you wouldn't be getting Optional. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good way to do it, and unwrap it safley

```
guard let param = codeParam else { return }
guard let value = param.value else { return }
print(value)
```

Comment: `guard let value = codeParam?.value else { return }`